# Update field on account whenever a new task or event is created

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to count all open activities related to an account.
I have a controller class and two triggers on task and events. I am getting the right records for a related account but, I can not update the field because it gives,

```
System.FinalException: Record is read-only
```

The field I have on account is called open activities with api of open_activities__c when my code reaches to this section, It throws the above exception
Below is the code I am trying to implement.

```
public class ActivityCounter {

   public static void activityCount(List<Account> lst) { 
   List<Account> upd = new List<Account>();
   Set<ID> accidset = new Set<ID>();
   Integer TaskCount = 0;
   Integer EventCount = 0;
   for(Account acc: lst) {
   accidset.add(acc.Id);
   } 
   List<Task> tskLst = [Select Id From Task Where WhatId IN:accidset and Status!='Completed']; 
   TaskCount = tskLst.size();    
   System.debug('Size of open tasks: '+ TaskCount);    
   List<Event> evntLst = [Select Id From Event Where WhatId IN:accidset and  EndDateTime <= TODAY];
   EventCount = evntLst.size();
   System.debug('Size of open events: '+ EventCount);
   for(Account ac:lst) {
   ac.Open_Activities__c=TaskCount+EventCount;
   upd.add(ac);    
   }    
   update upd;

  }
}
```

and the triggers

```
trigger ActivityCountTrigger on Task (after insert,after update) {
 ActivityCounter.activityCount(Trigger.New);
}
```

```
trigger ActivityCountTrigger on Events (after insert,after update) {
 ActivityCounter.activityCount(Trigger.New);
}
```

The open_activities__c field is not read-only. I double checked it. I have no clue why I am getting this exception.
Please help me understanding the issue here.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool?  https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B45gWEAR

Comment: That will probably be the best answer for the OP

Comment: @NickCook, No, I have not. Since I am practicing apex, So, I wanted to do this using apex only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this code is not going to work for a number of reasons:

1. Your trigger is on Task, and you send `Trigger.New` to the `ActivityCounter` class. However, that class expects `List<Account>`, which is never going to be sent from those two triggers.
2. While I applaud your intent to bulkify, you're getting **all** the open tasks/events for **all** accounts. Not for each account. What you really want is an aggregate query that groups your tasks/events by AccountId and THEN you update your accounts.

Here is what I would do:

1. Get your counter properly set (I changed the header in preparation for my next suggestion)

```
public static void activityCount(Set<Id> accountIds) { 
   List<Account> acctToUpdate = new List<Account>();

   Map<Id, Double> tasksByAccount = new Map<Id, Double>();
   for (AggregateResult agg : [Select WhatId, count(Id) cnt From Task Where WhatId IN :accountIds and Status != 'Completed' GROUP BY WhatId]) {
     Id accId = (Id) agg.get('WhatId');
     Double cnt = (Double) agg.get('cnt');

     tasksByAccount.put(accId, cnt);
   }

   Map<Id, Double> eventsByAccount = new Map<Id, Double>();
   for(AggregateResult> agg : [Select  WhatId, count(Id) cnt From Event Where WhatId IN :accountIds and  EndDateTime <= TODAY GROUP BY WhatId]) {
     Id accId = (Id) agg.get('WhatId');
     Double cnt = (Double) agg.get('cnt');

     eventsByAccount.put(accId, cnt);
   }

   for(Id accountId : accountIds) {
     Integer taskCount = tasksByAccount.containsKey(accountId) ? tasksByAccount.get(accountId) : 0;
     Integer eventCount = eventsByAccount.containsKey(accountId) ? eventsByAccount.get(accountId) : 0;

     Account acc = new Account(Id = accountId, Open_Activities__c=(taskCount + eventCount) );

     acctToUpdate.add(ac);    
   }    

   update acctToUpdate;

  }
```

2. Get your triggers to pass a `Set<Id>` instead of a `List<Account>`. One way to do this (for Tasks, I leave events to you) would be like this

```
trigger ActivityCountTrigger on Task (after insert, after update) {
  Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();

  for (Task t : trigger.New) {
    //I Have to check this is an account and not something else
    if (t.WhoId.startsWith(Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix()) {
      acctIds.add(t.WhoId);
    }
  }

  ActivityCounter.activityCount(acctIds);
}
```

**Notes**:

- There are many more improvements to make here (namely trying to consolidate both queries, using `IsClosed` and verifying that the status closed in your trigger)
- I posted this without being able to compile it (was not in a place where I could do so), please excuse and work-around any typos.

Comment: Yes, you want `whatId` and not `whoId`. That's what happens when you type directly here and can't test your code.  I also fixed a couple of minor things, but this should still work.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. I had made changes in the previous code you suggested same like you did here. It worked for me and now I know a way on how to do such kind of task.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're passing `Trigger.new` into your `activityCount()` method.

The `activityCount()` method is expecting a list of `Account` records, but `Trigger.new` is either a list of `Task` or `Event` records.

You're then adding the items within the trigger list to your `upd` variable, and because this is an after trigger, you cannot perform DML on it.

Comment: He should be able to perform DML on accounts if the trigger is Task/Event, as it is indicated in the post

Comment: But it's the passed in trigger that he's trying to perform DML on, not a freshly created list of accounts, hence the 'Record is read-only' exception.  The question was about the exception after all.

Comment: I guarantee that code doesn't even compile. You can't pass `trigger.new` from a Task Trigger into `List<Account>`. Just won't work. :) The OP has mixed a couple of things and thrown them in this post

Comment: lol.  I assumed that because he's got the exception, it must have compiled somehow.

Comment: Yeah, I think he started on an Account trigger, got the error, and later realized there were other things wrong.

Comment: DLRS seems to be a good use case for the OP, though, just in case, I put some code up there for him

Comment: @SebastianKessel, You are right. I started on account trigger and it was compiling and later i realized that i need the open activities field updated when a task or event is created. So, I changed the trigger from account to task and event. But, I did not compile it before posting the question here. I was getting the exception while i was compiling the account trigger. I did not realize before posting my question about that stupid mistake I am making by changing account trigger to task and event trigger. Thank you for pointing out. I will give a try to what you have suggested.

Comment: @SebastianKessel, I have a question about the solution you gave above, Why do we need WhoId here? for account, shouldn't we be working with WhatId? because tasks and events are related to account with whatId. In trigger, The who Id gives null object reference exception. I changed it to whatid and it runs. But, still it does not calculate the value in the open field, it shows 0.